# Custom service created using gunicorn in Ubuntu is throwing Error but Gunicorn funtion alone works perfectly fine

Tags: python, gunicorn, systemd

Having Issue with Service that i Created.

```
gunicorn –bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:application
```

This works well no issue at all

but with the Service… i get error

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve lolf
Wants = network-online.target
After = network.target network-online.target

[Service]
User=lolfbwu1
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/lolfbw/lolf
Environment=“PATH=/home/lolfbw/lolf/lolfenv/bin”
ExecStart=/home/lolfbw/lolf/lolfenv/bin/gunicorn –workers 3 –bind unix:lolf.sock -m 007 wsgi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Error i am getting:

> gunicorn[27945]: finalstart =
> datetime.fromisoformat(formatedstart).timestamp()
>
> gunicorn[27945]: ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: ’ 00:00:00’

But i don’t get this error when running it as

```
gunicorn –bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:application
```

Any Idea why is that…?

I am using Python3.9

Comment: Welcome to SO. While your post is well formatted and shows a lot of information, you might want to come up with a better title. This one might not attract as much interest as you might expect. Try to describe _what_ issue you are having.

Comment: All good... Give me solution if you have any idea on this